# Rest method does not get the proper data

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, curl, restful-architecture

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file. I've defined this Rest method to update a User

```
@PutMapping(path = "/api/users/{id}", 
                        consumes = "application/json", 
                        produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser
                                    (HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    @PathVariable long id,
                                    User user) {

        System.out.println(user);
        saveUser (user)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);

    }
```

I call this method from the console, using

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNhcmQub2xsZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MjgxMTM3NTIsImlhdCI6MTUyNzUwODk1Mn0.QdxabtU1U87pYvyTstT1EG3E6uVpLo2mXCF0FF8iD6acKoAXKl_A0-eV_GrpOFg5FF1qR6B7llI5_USJL85YTQ" -d '{
\"id\":1,\"username\":\"pere.peris@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"pere.peris@gmail.com\",\"firstName\":\"Pere\",\"lastName\":\"PERIS\",\"country\":\"CAT\",\"enabled\":true}' "http://127.0.0.1:2233/iCrypts/api/users/1"
```

But on the  `System.out.println(user);` all the values I get from the POJO are null (!?), but the `id` that is 1

Comment: What does your `User` class look like? Also, you should add a `@RequestBody` annotation on your `User user` parameter as I believe that Spring by default expects a request parameter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestBody` annotation is missing

```
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser
                                (HttpServletRequest request, 
                                @PathVariable long id,
                                @RequestBody User user) {
......
```

}

THe reason it contains `id` with value `1` is it must be getting auto-generated at persistance layer.